# How to add column names in excel into list in asp.net

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-core, asp.net-web-api

I want the elements of the first column of an Excel sheet to be added to the list.

This is my code:

```
var list = new List<string>();

using (var stream = new MemoryStream())
{
    await file.CopyToAsync(stream);

    ExcelPackage.LicenseContext = LicenseContext.NonCommercial;

    using (var package = new ExcelPackage(stream))
    {
        ExcelWorksheet worksheet = package.Workbook.Worksheets[0];
        var rowcount = worksheet.Dimension.Rows;
        var columncount = worksheet.Dimension.Columns;
        var column = worksheet.Rows[1].Range.Value;
        var range = worksheet.Rows.Range.Value;
        var row = worksheet.Columns[1].Range.Value;

        list.Add(column.ToString());
    }
}
```

Comment: Not very clear - is the for the classic "ASP.NET" - or the new ASP.NET **Core** ? You've tagged both ..... and is this for an MVC web app, or a Web API - again, you've tagged both. Please only use **actually relevant and applicable** tags! Don't tag spam ....

Answer (score -1):

```
for(int i = 1; i <= columncount; i++)
{
      var field1 = worksheet.Cells[1,i].Value as string;
      list.Add(field1);
      field1 = null;
}
```

this loop will give the first column names

Comment: why would you null the variable after using it? instead a null check could be useful, also this is likely doing the opposite than the author wants